# Changing a wordpress video plugin to auto-set youtube iframe parameters

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, iframe, youtube

I have a website that uses visual composer's video player element. By default, it only accepts the youtube URL and builds it's own iframe.

I need the iframes to reflect the following:

- No Recommendations (rel=0)
- Enable Youtube API (enablejsapi=1)
- Modest branding (modestbranding=1)

So the iframes will end with

```
?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&modestbranding=1
```

I got the idea that I would simple tell the plugin to do this by default but I'm afraid I'm only a beginner. I managed to find the vc_video.php file and I can see the embed setup. I just have no idea how to change it.

Here is the vc_video.php code. I've attempted to edit a couple of things but it just keeps breaking the player. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
/**
 * Shortcode attributes
 * @var $atts
 * @var $title
 * @var $link
 * @var $el_class
 * @var $css
 * Shortcode class
 * @var $this WPBakeryShortCode_VC_Video
 */
$output = '';
$atts = vc_map_get_attributes( $this->getShortcode(), $atts );
extract( $atts );

if ( '' === $link ) {
    return null;
}
$el_class = $this->getExtraClass( $el_class );

$video_w = ( isset( $content_width ) ) ? $content_width : 500;
$video_h = $video_w / 1.61; //1.61 golden ratio
/** @var WP_Embed $wp_embed */
global $wp_embed;
$embed = '';
if ( is_object( $wp_embed ) ) {
    $embed = $wp_embed->run_shortcode( '[embed width="' . $video_w . '"' . $video_h . ']' . $link . '[/embed]' );
}
$css_class = apply_filters( VC_SHORTCODE_CUSTOM_CSS_FILTER_TAG, 'wpb_video_widget wpb_content_element' . $el_class . $el_class . vc_shortcode_custom_css_class( $css, ' ' ), $this->settings['base'], $atts );

$output .= "\n\t" . '<div class="' . esc_attr( $css_class ) . '">';
$output .= "\n\t\t" . '<div class="wpb_wrapper">';
$output .= wpb_widget_title( array( 'title' => $title, 'extraclass' => 'wpb_video_heading' ) );
$output .= '<div class="wpb_video_wrapper">' . $embed . '</div>';
$output .= "\n\t\t" . '</div> ' . $this->endBlockComment( '.wpb_wrapper' );
$output .= "\n\t" . '</div> ' . $this->endBlockComment( $this->getShortcode() );

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

ADD AFTER LINE 36:

```
$embed = str_ireplace("feature=oembed", "feature=oembed&controls=0&rel=0", $embed);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, including an [explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/305455) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!